# There is JBAS011469 error when the app trying to write data to db. (JBossAS7, MySql)

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, jsf, jboss

I am newbie in the Java EE world. To improve my programming experience I chose the JBoss Developer Studio, and the JBoss AS 7 server with MySQL database. I use these tools in Fedora 20.
JBoss has a sample application ([jboss-as-kitchensink.zip](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/827503/44ums/jboss-as-kitchensink.zip) ) and I would like to create my own simple sample application like this example. The kitchensink sample use xml to store data, I'm using MySql. 
I cannot insert to data from jsf page. If I tried I've got this message to the console:

```
INFO [com.itemsapp.service.ItemInsertion] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) Inserting Lenovo 
INFO [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.renderkit] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) WARNING: FacesMessage(s) have been enqueued, but may not have been displayed. 
sourceId=null[severity=(ERROR 2), summary=(JBAS011469: Transaction is required to perform this operation (either use a transaction or extended persistence context)), detail=(Insertation unsuccessful)]
```

But if I insterted data maunaly, I could get the that from the database [image: as you can see here] .

```
INSERT INTO `itemsapp`.`ITEM`(`ITEM_ID`,`ITEM_PRICE`,`MODEL_NO`,`NAME`,`TOTAL_NO`)VALUES(1,250,"Inspiron 3520","DELL",12);
SELECT * FROM itemsapp.ITEM;
```

I archived my project from jbdevstudio https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/827503/44ums/ItemsApp_jsf_kts.zip .

What am i doing wrong?

Does someone have any idea how to change this code?

Thank you in advance for any help you can provide.

P.S.: The links points Dropbox links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first glance, the error you received means that your application needs a transaction in order to persist your item instance object in the mysql database.

I did not see the JBoss example, but persistence (as in JPA : Java Persistence API) is surely not required when using a flat xml storage.

So you need to declare a persistence unit (in a persistence.xml file within META-INF folder), and access it through an EntityManager.

As you are starting in the wonderful JEE world, I would advise you to pick up a sample persistence app, rather than adapting one that only persists your instances to XML. Empty projects may be available as [Maven archetypes](http://www.mastertheboss.com/maven-hibernate-jpa/maven-and-jpa-tutorial)

I found vogella tutorials to be very helpful when learning Java technologies : see this [one](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaPersistenceAPI/article.html).

One last word : JPA is the API ; Hibernate, or EclipseLink, or other ORMs are the implementation of JPA (Hibernate extends it though).

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

I guess I solved this problem.
At the com.itemsapp.service package i annotated the ItemInsertion class with @Stateless annotation. Now i've got the 
sourceId=null[severity=(INFO 0), summary=(Inserted!), detail=(Insertation successful)]

And i can see the data in the db and the listItems.xhtml too.

I'm learning JavaEE one-two month ago and I created some version of this app ([here is the examples](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/827503/44ums/itemsapps.zip)). I want to create this also with MAven. So thats link what you shared on your comment is great to me to try do my project with MAven.

Regards,
Adrian